# Polynomials in character form to numeric (SAS)

Tags: sas, character, numeric, polynomials

I have a SAS dataset which contains one column of polynomials. For example, X1**(-2)+X1**(2).

Is there a function to transform this into a numeric expression?

Many thanks,

Comment: Please confirm - you have a dataset that contains a character variable whose values are polynomial expressions? Do you already have a numeric variable called x1 in the same dataset?

Comment: Yes, the variable X1 is a continuous variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I don't think there is a specific function that will easily let you do this. You have two options - write your own logic to interpret the polynomial expressions, or use `call execute` to have SAS write out a (potentially very long) data step for you, assuming that the polynomials are all entered as valid data step code. Here's a `call execute` approach:

```
data have;
input x1 polynomial $255.;
infile datalines truncover;
datalines;
1 X1**(-2)+X1**(2)
2 X1**(-1)+X1**(1)
3 X1**(1)+X1**(-1)
;
run;

data _null_;
 set have end = eof;
 if _n_ = 1 then call execute('data want; set have; select(_n_);');
 call execute(catx(' ','when(',_N_,') y =',polynomial,';'));
 if eof then call execute('end; run;');
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert them to macro variables, and then resolve them into a calculation...

Using the dataset example in user667489's answer :

```
/* Create numbered macro variables, 1 per row of data */
data _null_ ;
  set have end=eof ;

  call symputx(cats('POLY',_n_),polynomial) ;
  if eof then call symputx('POLYN',_n_) ;
run ;

%MACRO ROWLOOPER ;
  %DO N = 1 %TO &POLYN ;
    if _n_ = &N then result = &&POLY&N ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;

data want ;
  set have ;

  /* Not very efficient, looping over all polynomials on each row of data */  
  /* So for 3 rows, you'll perform 9 iterations here */
  %ROWLOOPER ;
run ;
```

Or, alternatively, write your dataset out into a SAS program, and `%inc` that program :

```
data _null_ ;
  file "polynomials.sas" ;
  set have end=eof ;
  if _n_ = 1 then do ;
    put "data poly;" ;
    put "  set have;" ;
  end ;

  put "  result = " polynomial ";" ;

  if eof then put "run;" ;
run ;

%inc "polynomials.sas" ;
```